# Select a single polygon in a FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, polygon, javascript, google

I am currently trying to perform a supervised classification in Google Earth Engine (GEE) for which I have a set of polygons of areas with forest plantations.

[image]

The FeatureCollection I have shows me, among other things, the department and the id of each of the polygons with plantations.
Is there a way to call a single polygon (eg the one with ID = 503883) by any of its properties? Can that single polygon be displayed using the "Map.addlayer" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a filter to select the specific feature. In this case your filter would be:

```
var selectedFeature = fc.filter(ee.Filter.eq('id', 503883));
```